# How to force iPhone into fullscreen landscape mode when playing video thru UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, media-player, landscape

In my app I have a tab that brings in a mobile website in a UIWebView and the mobile site basically has a list of videos that you can play. When I click to play one, it plays the video but I can't get it to go into fullscreen landscape mode, when I rotate it just stays in portrait orientation.

Is there a way using MediaPlayer framework to detect when a video is playing and allow fullscreen landscape orientation for this particular case?

All i've been able to locate is doing it when loading a movie directly with a url, but I'm not, Im loading a .html in a web view, then playing videos through that website.

Any way I can make it shift to landscape?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your UIWebViewDelegate, implement the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and when you detect a movie, use the MediaPlayer.framework.

Comment: Probably duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489852/how-to-force-view-to-enter-landscape-in-ios