# Force WKWebview always playing video url in landscape mode and full screen?

Tags: ios, video, fullscreen, wkwebview, landscape

I want to force the WKWebview playing video in landscape mode and full screen, even the device is locked rotation. It is similar to the full screen mode of youtube app.

How can I archieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489852/how-to-force-view-to-enter-landscape-in-ios)